# How to find all the real roots of $x^9 - 2021x^3 + \sqrt{2020}$= $0$

Tags: polynomials

Here's my attempt:

Let $x^3$ = $t$

then the equation turns into:

$t^3 -2021t + \sqrt{2020} = 0$
$t^3 - t = 2020t - \sqrt{2020}$
$t(t^2-1) = (\sqrt{2020})(\sqrt{2020}t - 1)$

From here you can see a root t=$\sqrt{2020}$ or $x = \sqrt[6]{2020}$
but now I don't know how to find the other 8 possible roots.

Comment: Without $e^{i\pi}$ representation, after solving cubic (you can apply polynomial long division rule,  if you know one real root and you will get a quadratic) $$x^3-(\sqrt [3]{t})^3=0$$ Then apply $$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=0$$

Comment: Since you have one root of the cubic in $t$, take out a linear factor, then solve a quadratic.

Comment: @TobyMak I wrote "$x$"= $\sqrt[6]{2020}$

Comment: @J.G. but wouldn't that be extremely time consuming approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A related substitution to use would be $x^3=\sqrt{2020}y$ which yields

$$2020y^3-2021y+1=0$$

Clearly $y=1$ is a root of this equation by rational root theorem, so we can factor this into

$$(y-1)(2020y^2+2020y-1)=0$$

by polynomial long division. Quadratic equation gives the last two solutions in $y$ to be

$$y = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2020}} = -\frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{506}{505}}$$

Of these three solutions, each of them corresponds to three solutions in $x$ corresponding to their (scaled) cube roots in the complex plane, all of which are colinear (from the origin) with the cube roots of unity or their negatives. Therefore the original equation only has three real solutions.